# REST API - appropriate response statuses

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I'm designing a REST API. I would like to know what are the most appropriate http statuses in the 2 following scenarios:

A user tries to register and:

1. Username already exists.

OR:

2. Password and password repeat fields do not match.

Thanks.

Comment: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

Answer (score 1):

> Username already exists

`409 Conflict` sounds correct for this situation.

> Password or password repeat fields do not match

This is a general error on the client side. Use `400 Bad Request` for this.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes for more.

Answer (score 0):

`409` status code is a good choice for a username that already exists:

> [**6.5.8 409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict.

`400` status code is just fine for passwords that do not match:

> [**6.5.1.  400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot
> or will not process the request due to something that is perceived
> to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid
> request message framing, or deceptive request routing).